# How to store formed command line without running it in bash or terminal?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, terminal

For example, I have formed a long complicated command that will improve the world and lower an entropy in the Universe. But then (huh!) I see that I forgot to make a dir required. I want to store my command, run `mkdir` and then restore my command.

Assume doing it in a raw tty.

Is there a way to do so?

Comment: I'm assuming you can't copy and paste? Just put a # at the beginning of the line and then run it. It'll be stored in the bash history where you can retrieve it, delete the # and the run it properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your command-line press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>u</kbd> (it stores it in the  kill-ring), issue the other one `mkdir` for example, and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>y</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Use `set -o vi` command or `set -o emacs` (typically one would store this in .bashrc for convenience). This enables a vi-style (or emacs type) line editing interface.

This provides you with a command line vi editor. You can search for previous commands, edit commands, etc.

**Examples:**

Use ESC key to enter vi command mode, then

```
$ /search-string
```

Use UP and DOWN keys, (or `j` and `k`) to list found commands

```
$ long-command-you-want-to-edit
```

Hit ESC key
type `vi`
Then edit the long command in a vi editor.